# guard live reload not injecting css changes to page. Sinatra app

Tags: css, sinatra, sass, reload, guard

I have a sinatra app using the rack-livereload and guard-livereload gems.

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)$})
  watch(%r{.+\.(css|js)$})
end
```

When I make changes to my erb files, the browser reloads. It works as expected.

I'm using the sass gem for my css.

When I make changes to my .scss file, the css is not updating. The changes are not visible in the browser until I refresh the page. The sass is working - but is not being picked up by active reload.

Any idea how I set this up?

Comment: Are you using `@include` in your scss?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not reloading because the regex in the watch statement is only looking for files that end with .css or .js. If you want to make sure your .scss files get included, just change the watch statement to this:

```
watch(%r{.+\.(css|scss|js)$})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another stylesheet that was missing from the page (404) stopped livereload from working for my case, it wasn't the stylesheet in concern but it prevent livereload from detecting the change in the one that I was making.